# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo , Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

This Question Has been asked so many time and i have tried all the solutions .Can you help me find what is missing in my code.

LOGCAT ERROR

FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gencgonulluler/com.example.gencgonulluler.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.gencgonulluler.Etkinlikler.name' on a null object reference in method 'void com.example.gencgonulluler.DetailActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)'
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.gencgonulluler.Etkinlikler.name' on a null object reference in method 'void com.example.gencgonulluler.DetailActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle)'

1)my DetailActivity code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.gencgonulluler.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ActivityDetailBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

       // Etkinlikler selectedLandmark = (Etkinlikler) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Etkinlikler");
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
        Etkinlikler selectedEtkinlikler = singleton.getSelectedEtkinlikler();

        binding.etkinliklerNameText.setText(selectedEtkinlikler.name);
        binding.countryNameText.setText(selectedEtkinlikler.country);
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(selectedEtkinlikler.image);

    }
    public void changeScreen(View view){
        Intent intent =new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and activity_detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gencgonulluler.DetailActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryNameText"
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/country_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etkinliklerNameText"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/etkinliklerNameText"
        android:layout_width="273dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="changeScreen"
        android:text="@string/ana_men"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/countryNameText" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2)my Etkinlikler code:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Etkinlikler implements Serializable {

        String name;
        String country;
        int image;

        public Etkinlikler(String name, String country, int image) {
            this.name = name;
            this.country = country;
            this.image = image;
        }


}
```

Due to this issue, the app closes just before launching. I am not getting any error other than logcat error when starting it in android studio

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```java
        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();
        Etkinlikler selectedEtkinlikler = singleton.getSelectedEtkinlikler();

        binding.etkinliklerNameText.setText(selectedEtkinlikler.name);
```

Based on this code and the stack trace, `selectedEtkinlikler` is `null`, but `singleton` is not. So, your problem lies in `Singleton` and its `getSelectedEtkinlikler()` method somewhere.

Comment: my codes for singelton :   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class Singleton  {
    private Etkinlikler selectedEtkinlikler;
    private static Singleton singleton;
    private Singleton() {
  }
    public Etkinlikler getSelectedEtkinlikler() {
     return selectedEtkinlikler;
  }
    public void setChosenEtkinlikler(Etkinlikler selectedEtkinlikler) {
     this.selectedEtkinlikler = selectedEtkinlikler;
  }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {

     if (singleton == null) {
      singleton = new Singleton();
  }
       return singleton;
  }
}